# Equivalent MongoDB Query of SQL Query

Tags: mongodb

I am a newbie in MongoDB. I want to make the equivalent mongoDB query of this sql query

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id IN
(SELECT follower_id FROM followers WHERE user_id = '@userid')
ORDERBY timestamp
```

This sql query list outs all the posts from followed users ordered by timestamp.

If there are two collections for users and posts then how can i write the equivalent query in mongoDB
Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Haven't done anything in mongo for a long time (so cant give much details), but the example [for the $lookup operator in the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries)  looks exactly like what you want.

Comment: Thanks @enricog  for your response.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id IN
(SELECT follower_id FROM followers WHERE user_id = '@userid')
ORDERBY timestamp

above SQL translates to below MongoDB Aggregation Query:

```
db.posts.aggregate([{$lookup: {
  from: 'followers',
  localField: 'user_id',
  foreignField: 'user_id',
  as: 'userFollowes' 
}}, {$unwind: {
  path: '$userFollowes',
  preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false 
}}, {$match: {
  "userFollowes.user_id": "user1" 
}}, {$sort: {
  timestamp: -1
}}, {$project: {
userFollowes:0

  }}])
```

Optimized version of it would be using lookup with conditions to ensure we just do lookup (join) on data we are interested in.

aggregation has below stages:

1. lookup (does join or inner query to match data with followers based on user_id)
2. unwind (seperates each records if multiple records found in followers based on user_id)
3. match (does filter criteria of user_id = '@userid')
4. sort (does orderby timestamp)
5. project (does select * from post)

[image]

Tip of the Day!: you can use below code and copy paste in aggregation tab (in New Pipeline From Plain Text option down arrow beside + icon) for posts collection in compass to see the query output in debug mode!

```
[{$lookup: {
  from: 'followers',
  localField: 'user_id',
  foreignField: 'user_id',
  as: 'userFollowes' 
}}, {$unwind: {
  path: '$userFollowes',
  preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false 
}}, {$match: {
  "userFollowes.user_id": "user1" 
}}, {$sort: {
  timestamp: -1
}}, {$project: {
userFollowes:0

  }}]
```